# MySql and JDBC: change charset of a single column to utf8mb4

Tags: mysql, jdbc, utf-8, utf8mb4

I have an "old" database (in utf 8) where I read and write on by using JDBC. Now, I must be able to also store emoji into a column of my table. 
I have changed the charset of involved columns to utf8mb4:

```
ALTER TABLE
myTable
CHANGE column_name column_name
longtext
CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
NOT NULL;
```

However, when I try to insert an emoticon into that column, I get the famous error

```
java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x91\x8D\xF0\x9F...'
```

Should I convert entire database, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Which version of MySQL Connector/J do you use, and what connection properties do you use? Have you set the MySQL server property character_set_server to utf8mb4 or not?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE myTable` -- I won't to verify that the column is declared correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Need to *connect* with utf8mb4 to get , etc.

`?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8` in the `getConnection()` call.

<strike>As a fallback, execute `SET NAMES utf8mb4` after connecting. 
 (See Comment.)</strike>

"For Connector/J 8.0.12 and earlier: In order to use the `utf8mb4` character set for the connection, the server MUST be configured with `character_set_server=utf8mb4`; if that is not the case, when UTF-8 is used for characterEncoding in the connection string, it will map to the MySQL character set name `utf8`, which is an alias for `utf8mb3`.'

Comment: The [MySQL Connector/J documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-charsets.html) explicitly says to not use `SET NAMES`: _"Warning: Do not issue the query SET NAMES with Connector/J, as the driver will not detect that the character set has been changed by the query, and will continue to use the character set configured when the connection was first set up."_

Comment: Confirmed with MySQL Connector/J version 8.0.17. All that's required is `useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8` in the connection URL. That was true even when the server's default character set was `latin1` and the database's default character set was `utf8` (not `utf8mb4`).